# Finding all finite field embeddings

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, math-software, magma-cas

Does there exist an efficient (i.e. sub-exponential) algorithm for finding all possible embeddings of one finite field into an isomorphic field? I'm particularly interested in ways to embed $GF((2^2)^2)$ into $GF(2^4)$ and $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ into $GF(2^8)$. Finding a single embedding can be easily done using tools like Magma, but as far as I know this embedding is selected at random the approach discussed here (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717197901383). Beyond from trying the embedding many, many times and hoping that all possibilities are covered, I was not able to find a enumerate all of these embeddings. Does anyone know how? Better yet, if there is support to do this in Magma, can someone provide an example?

Comment: What is the difference between $GF((2^2)^2)$ and $GF(2^4)$ in the first place? Both are simply $GF(16)$.

Comment: Yes, they're isomorphic, but elements in each are represented differently. $GF((2^2)^2)$ is defined by a degree 2 irreducible polynomial over $GF(2^2)$, whereas $GF(2^4)$ is defined by a degree 4 irreducible polynomial over $GF(2)$. I want to embed $GF((2^2)^2)$ into $GF(2^4)$ so that addition and multiplication homomorphism holds.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $k$ and $k'$ are finite fields of size $q$ and $q'$ respectively
and characteristic $p$, with $q=p^f$.
If you can efficiently find one embedding $\iota: k \rightarrow k'$,
you can find all others by composing $\iota$ with $\sigma^m$ for $0<m<f$,
where $\sigma: x \mapsto x^p$ is the generator of $\text{Aut}(k)$.
(note that $\sigma$ can be evaluated efficiently by square-and-multiply).

Comment: I'm not sure what you by composing the embedding with all conjugates of the generator $\sigma$. I'm also unfamiliar with the notation Gal($k'/k$). Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not conjugates of $\sigma$ but powers of $\sigma$.  Gal is Galois group.
But I messed up: I should have written powers of the generator 
$x \mapsto x^p$ of $\text{Aut}(k)$.  That is, if you have an embedding
$\iota$ that takes every $x\in k$ to $\iota(x) \in k'$, then another
embedding would take every $x$ to $(\iota(x))^p$
a third embedding taking every $x$ to $(\iota(x))^{p^2}$,
etc. until some $p^f = q$ at which point
 $(\iota(x))^{p^f} = \iota(x)$ and there are no more embeddings to be found.  Let me fix this...

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you very much for the fix!

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Can you answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583960/how-to-find-the-embedding-between-finite-fields please?

Answer (score 0):

As the multiplicative group of a finite field $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is cyclic, just pick a generator $g$ of $\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times$ and try the maps $g\mapsto g^k$ with $1\le k< p^n$ and $(k,p^n-1)=1$.
Especially, the case $k=p$ is called Frobenius automorphism.

Comment: Surely you know that this gives a homomorphism of fields if and only if $k$ is a power of $p$?!?